# Displaying all the members of database in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to make a predicate "find_recipe" which fetches a list of ingredients based on the name of the recipe, given by the user.

I defined 3 recipes and am trying to first show a prompt for a user, let the user enter the recipe name, and then next few lines which are commented out should handle fetching the designated recipe, and lastly the line beginning with `format` will print out the result.

```
recipe('Makaronilaatikko', ['macaroni', 'potato', 'onion', 'cheese', 'milk', 'egg', 'minced meat']).
recipe('Curry rice', ['rice', 'curry powder', 'potato', 'onion', 'carrot', 'bacon']).
recipe('Sandwich', ['bread', 'onion', 'egg', 'bacon']).


find_recipe(Recipename, Result):-
    write(‘Enter the name of the recipe you want: ’), nl,
    read(Recipename),
    % go through the entire data of recipes defined
    % find the recipe whose name matches the use input
    format(‘Ingredients needed for ~w are ~w ~n’, [Recipename, Result]).
```

but I have no idea how the part

```
% go through the entire data of recipes defined
% find the recipe whose name matches the use input
```

should be implemented in Prolog, though I know I could write like

```
for(int i=0; i<recipeList.length;i++){
  Recipe result = new Recipe();
  if(recipeList[i].name == Recipename){
    result = recipeList[i]<
  }
  return result.ingredients;
}
```

if I were to write the same thing in a Java like language.

But how do I do this in Prolog?

And perhaps the recipes in my code above are defined in a wrong way in the first place?

**[UPDATE]**

This is the usage of find_recipe predicate I've been thinking of

```
main():-
    chooseusertype(Usertype),
    startas(Usertype),
    find_recipe(Recipename).  % somehow read the user's input, and then pass that to find_recipe predicate

find_recipe(Recipename, Result):-
    write(‘Enter the name of the recipe you want: ’), nl,
    read(Recipename),
    % go through the entire data of recipes defined
    % find the recipe whose name matches the use input
    format(‘Ingredients needed for ~w are ~w ~n’, [Recipename, Result]).

chooseusertype(X):-
    write('Log in as a merchant or customer?: '),
    read(X),
    format('Your log in type: ~w', [X]).

startas('merchant'):-
    write('Logged in as merchant'), nl,
    write('Any update on the shelves?').

startas('customer'):-
    write('Logged in as customer'), nl,
    write('Let us help you find the ingredients you want!'), nl.
    write('Enter the name of the recipe you want:'),
    % somehow read the user's input, and then pass that to find_recipe predicate
```

Comment: I am giving you a down-vote because you are changing the question after a valid answer has been given. Ask a new question and link that question to this question.  StackOverflow is not a discussion site, it is a question and answer site. You did ask a good question, and received a valid answer. But now you are moving the goal post.

Comment: The system will not let me change the down-vote to an up-vote. See: [Change a vote from downvote to upvote via editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23147/change-a-vote-from-downvote-to-upvote-via-editing)

Comment: In your new code, you ask to prove `find_recipe` with 1 argument, but when you define `find_recipe` it takes 2.  That is guaranteed to fail, regardless of what is done inside of `find_recipe`.

Comment: It let me undo the down-vote because the question was edited. If they ever put how the voting works here to a vote it does not get my vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (part of) what makes Prolog so beautiful; proving

```
recipe(RecipeName,Result)
```

when `RecipeName` has been bound to a value will result in `Result` being bound to the ingredients for that recipe; Prolog does the searching for you.

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to implement find_recipe is that I want to make another predicate in which find_recipe gets called with a user input. So unfortunately I don't think this answer addresses my problem.

Comment: So that predicate gets "called" with the recipe name bound, and the statement above will bind the matching ingredient list.  What is the problem?

Comment: Have you *tried* using this stament in the code you posted?

Comment: @furitetepporaa Scott has answered your question. I know you are learning Prolog and it doesn't work as you expected, but you are new to StackOverflow and by adding more to your original question `I want to make another predicate in which find_recipe gets called with a user input.` you are actually asking an entirely different question. You should start a new question and link from that question to this question and give Scott the accept vote. It is not Scott's fault you that you were not precise in your question.